# R: Crear un nuevo Data Frame con las 10 últimas columnas de mi actual data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy intentando crear un nuevo data frame a partir de mis datos actuales (mi data frame original) y quiero seleccionar las 10 últimas columnas de mi actual data frame (son 83 columnas en total, y quiero seleccionar las últimas 10: 74,75,76,77...83 (con todas sus filas, en este caso 1460 filas)

Para ello, escribo `datos_ultimos = tail(datosNum[,c(74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83)], n = 1460)` pero me dice R:  *Error in `[.data.frame`(datosNum, , c(74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,  :
undefined columns selected*

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar las diez últimas columnas para el nuevo data frame? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si df es tu dataframe, prueba a ver si sale con esto

```
inicio <- ncol(df)-9
fin <- ncol(df)

df[, inicio:fin]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bien sintética de resolverlo con R base sería:

```
datosNum[ ,tail(seq_along(datosNum), 10)]
```

Con `seq_along(datosNum)` generamos una secuencia de 1 a la cantidad de columnas de `datosNum` y con `tail()` nos quedamos con las últimas